# Filtering a custom tuple in haskell

Tags: list, haskell, filter, tuples

Hey guys I'm working on a function that will output a the board of a board game as a string.
Currently I have it working so that I can output the board without any pieces.

I'm trying to add a filter so that if the current `(x, y)` coordinate is in the list of tuples `[Position, Col]` where `Position` is `(Int, Int)`.

If `(x, y)` is in this list then I want to check the colour `Col` and then output accordingly.

```
drawBoardCell :: (Int, Int) ->[(Position, Col)] -> String
drawBoardCell (x, y) pieces = do
      let test = filter (\((a,b),_) -> a == x && b == y) pieces
      if snd(test) == Black
            then " b "
      else if snd(test) == White
            then " w "
      else " . "
```

This is what i have tried so far and run into the error:

```
Display.hs:47:14: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘(a0, Col)’
                  with actual type ‘[((Int, Int), Col)]’
    • In the first argument of ‘snd’, namely ‘(test)’
      In the first argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘snd (test)’
      In the expression: snd (test) == Black

Display.hs:49:19: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘(a1, Col)’
                  with actual type ‘[((Int, Int), Col)]’
    • In the first argument of ‘snd’, namely ‘(test)’
      In the first argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘snd (test)’
      In the expression: snd (test) == White
```

Comment: The return value of `filter` is a list (`[a]`) so `test` is a list - the *actual type* in the error message. `snd`, on the other hand, expects a tuple - the *expected type* in the error message. These two types don't match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `test` is still a list `[(Position, Col)]`, so it can't be passed into `snd` which expects a single tuple `(a, b)`. If you can guarantee that there will be a match in your pieces array, then you should change your body to:

```
drawBoardCell (x, y) pieces =
  let [match] = filter (\((a,b),_) -> a == x && b == y) pieces
  case match of
    (_, Black) -> " b "
    (_, White) -> " w "
    _          -> " . "
```

Note the use of `case` here instead of `if`. It's not strictly necessary, but it's cleaner when comparing a value against multiple options to match this way.

If, however, as I suspect is the case, you might have 0 or 1 matches, you need to use something like the following instead:

```
drawBoardCell (x, y) pieces = do
  case filter (\((a,b),_) -> a == x && b == y) pieces of
    [(_, Black)] -> " b "
    [(_, White)] -> " w "
    _            -> " . "
```

This will print `" . "` if the value is not present in the filtered list, if the value is present multiple times, or if the `Col` of the single match is neither `White` nor `Black`.

It is pointed out in the comments that you may want to handle no matches and multiple matches differently. In this case:

```
drawBoardCell (x, y) pieces = do
  case filter (\((a,b),_) -> a == x && b == y) pieces of
    [(_, Black)] -> " b "
    [(_, White)] -> " w "
    []           -> " . "  -- Case of no matches
    _            -> error "Multiple pieces cannot occupy the same position " ++ show (x, y)
```

This example will cause a Runtime error if the list has multiple matches (which can be useful for debugging).

Comment: your code is prima facie erroneous. you might have domain knowledge that there won't ever be any duplicates in that list (position-wise), but it is not self-evident in the code. that's why I used those patterns that I did in my answer. in case there were any duplicates, your second code won't use any of them. and the first will error out.

Comment: @WillNess I explain the assumptions I made within the answer. It's quite clear I think that the second solution only works for "0 or 1 matches." Having some familiarity with board games, I would expect that multiple pieces appearing at the same position on the board is an error condition. I considered putting the cases as `[] -> " . "; _ -> error "Multiple pieces cannot occupy the same position"` but I know that `error` is frowned upon, so I decided against it.

Comment: this does not contradict what I said. :) You may well be absolutely sure the bad case won't ever happen, it's just not self-evident in the code, on the contrary. Explicit error is *much* better than the possibility of an unhandled one. You *know* that it won't ever happen, so having that error message is harmless and serves as (additional) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

`filter` returns a list, but `snd` expects a tuple. These are different types.

You could tweak your conditional as

```
      if snd(head test) == Black
            then " b "
      else if snd(head test) == White
            then " w "
      else " . "
```

but what if `test` is an *empty* list, `[]`?

You could code this as

```
      if not (null test) && snd(head test) == Black
            then " b "
      else not (null test) && if snd(head test) == White
            then " w "
      else " . "
```

but this is not a very nice Haskell. Instead, we can get a bit better code with *pattern matching*:

```
      case  test  of
        ((_,Black):_) -> " b "
        ((_,White):_) -> " w "
        _             -> " . "
```

Or restructure your code to use

```
find :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe a
```

instead of the

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

You can use [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=find) to find out more.